# how to scrape nested two elements with python

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping

hi i would like to get some info which is on below **< del> and < ins> tags** but i could not find any solution for it can is anyone has idea about this scraping and is there any for getting those informations

this is my python code
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
  header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'}
  
  base_url = "https://www.n11.com/super-firsatlar"
  
  r = requests.get(base_url,headers=header)
  
  if r.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    books = soup.find_all('li',attrs={"class":"column"})
    result=[]
    for book in books:
      title=book.find('h3').text
      link=base_url +book.find('a')['href']
      picture = base_url + book.find('img')['src']
      price=book.find('p', {'class': 'del'})
      single ={'title':title,'link':link,'picture':picture,'price':price}
      result.append(single)
      with open('book.json','w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(result,f,indent=4,ensure_ascii=False)
  else:
    print(r.status_code)
```

and this my html page

```html
<li class="column">
    <script type="text/javascript">
var customTextOptionMap = {};
    </script>
    <div id="p-457010862" class="columnContent ">
        <div class="pro">
            <a href="https://www.n11.com/urun/oppo-a73-128-gb-oppo-turkiye-garantili-1599155?magaza=gelecekbizde"
               title="Oppo A73 128 GB (Oppo Türkiye Garantili)" class="plink" data-id="457010862">
                <img data-original="https://n11scdn1.akamaized.net/a1/215/elektronik/cep-telefonu/oppo-a73-128-gb-oppo-turkiye-garantili__1298508275589871.jpg"
                     width="215" height="215"
                     src="https://n11scdn1.akamaized.net/a1/215/elektronik/cep-telefonu/oppo-a73-128-gb-oppo-turkiye-garantili__1298508275589871.jpg"
                     alt="Oppo A73 128 GB (Oppo Türkiye Garantili)" class="lazy" style="">
                <h3 class="productName ">
                    Oppo A73 128 GB (Oppo Türkiye Garantili)</h3>
                <span class="loading"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="proDetail">
            <a href="https://www.n11.com/urun/oppo-a73-128-gb-oppo-turkiye-garantili-1599155?magaza=gelecekbizde"
               class="oldPrice" title="Oppo A73 128 GB (Oppo Türkiye Garantili)">


                <del>2.999, 00 TL</del>


            </a> <a href="https://www.n11.com/urun/oppo-a73-128-gb-oppo-turkiye-garantili-1599155?magaza=gelecekbizde"
                    class="newPrice" title="Oppo A73 128 GB (Oppo Türkiye Garantili)">


            <ins>2.899, 00<span content="TRY">TL</span></ins>



        </a>
            <div class="discount discountS">
                <div>
                    <span class="percent">%</span>
                    <span class="ratio">3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="textImg freeShipping"></span>
            <p class="catalogView-hover-separate"></p>
            <div class="moreOpt">
                <a title="Oppo A73 128 GB (Oppo Türkiye Garantili)" class="textImg moreOptBtn"
                   href="https://www.n11.com/urun/oppo-a73-128-gb-oppo-turkiye-garantili-1599155?magaza=gelecekbizde"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am not understanding your question, it should be as simple as doing:

```
del_data = soup.find_all("del")
ins_data = soup.find_all("ins")
```

is this not what you're trying to achieve? If not please clarify your question

Comment: i would like to get del and ins  datas from this page bu

Comment: what is the result you do what? im confused as to what data you are looking for

Comment: i am trying to get those data parse  to json  but it is not working

Comment: what do you mean "data parse to json"?? can you just write here exactly the result you expect so I can see what you need

Comment: "title": "\nOppo A73 128 GB (Oppo Türkiye Garantili)",
 "link": "https://www.n11.com/super-firsatlarhttps://www.n11.com/urun/oppo-a73-128-gb-oppo-turkiye-garantili-1599155?magaza=gelecekbizde",
        "picture": "https://www.n11.com/super-firsatlarhttps://n11scdn.akamaized.net/static/css/jquery/img/blank.gif",
        "price": 2999

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223888/discussion-between-avi-baruch-and-mehmet-resat-demir).

Answer (score 0):

`del` and `ins` are not `class` names but `tags`. You can simply find them with `Soup.find_all('del')`

```
price = book.find_all('del')
        for p in price:
            print(p.text)
```

gives
2.999,00 TL
189,90 TL
8.308,44 TL
499,90 TL
6.999,00 TL
99,00 TL
18,00 TL
499,00 TL
169,99 TL
1.499,90 TL
3.010,00 TL
2.099,90 TL
......
which is what you want I guess. You have to access the `text` attribute here. So, the element is located. The way you want to serialize it is a different question.

Comment: raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable

Comment: That is not an element find error. That is an JSON error. Which means the element cannot be formatted as a JSON object the way you want it. You need to ask another question for that. The element has been found.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: how can i serialize it